# Adjectives/verbs being used as nouns: the trend grows?

Tags: terminology, parts-of-speech, lexicon, derivation

- "I want a job with a social *connect*"   , using a verb *connect* for
  the noun *connection*.
- "It's a *fail*!" , using the verb *fail* instead of the noun *failure*.
- "Acme is a multinational corporate" , using the adjective *corporate* instead of "Corporate entity"
- "Increase in rep on SE due to an accept". Using verb accept instead of noun acceptance.
- "SE is upgrading its **compute**"

> Has such a usage been noted , what do we call it?
>   any examples of more such usage welcome.

Comment: Relevant terms are ***[conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation))***, ***[null morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_morpheme)***, and ***zero derivation***.

Comment: I thought it was called *nouning*.

Comment: That's another zero-derivation. And English is full of them; we're losing productive derivational morphology pretty fast.

Comment: ***Nouning*** and ***verbing*** are newer colloquial nontechnical terms (-: